# Weblogic Java thread getting stuck

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x, jrockit

I have a J2EE application running in Weblogic 10.3.6  that seems to randomly get 2 stuck threads and I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction as to what the struck threads might be waiting on. Here is the thread dump:

```
"Main Thread" id=1 idx=0x4 tid=12639 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked

            -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/t3/srvr/T3Srvr@0x92af6588[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)

            at weblogic/t3/srvr/T3Srvr.waitForDeath(T3Srvr.java:981)

            ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/t3/srvr/T3Srvr@0x92af6588[fat lock]

            at weblogic/t3/srvr/T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:490)

            at weblogic/Server.main(Server.java:71)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "(Signal Handler)" id=2 idx=0x8 tid=12640 prio=5 alive, native_blocked, daemon

        "(OC Main Thread)" id=3 idx=0xc tid=12641 prio=5 alive, native_waiting, daemon

        "(GC Worker Thread 1)" id=? idx=0x10 tid=12642 prio=5 alive, daemon

        "(GC Worker Thread 2)" id=? idx=0x14 tid=12643 prio=5 alive, daemon

        "(GC Worker Thread 3)" id=? idx=0x18 tid=12644 prio=5 alive, daemon



        "(Code Generation Thread 1)" id=4 idx=0x60 tid=12662 prio=5 alive, native_waiting, daemon

        "(Code Optimization Thread 1)" id=5 idx=0x64 tid=12663 prio=5 alive, native_waiting, daemon

        "(VM Periodic Task)" id=6 idx=0x68 tid=12664 prio=10 alive, native_blocked, daemon

        "Finalizer" id=7 idx=0x6c tid=12665 prio=8 alive, native_waiting, daemon

            at jrockit/memory/Finalizer.waitForFinalizees(J[Ljava/lang/Object;)I(Native Method)

            at jrockit/memory/Finalizer.access$700(Finalizer.java:12)

            at jrockit/memory/Finalizer$4.run(Finalizer.java:189)

            at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "Reference Handler" id=8 idx=0x70 tid=12666 prio=10 alive, native_waiting, daemon

            at java/lang/ref/Reference.waitForActivatedQueue(J)Ljava/lang/ref/Reference;(Native Method)

            at java/lang/ref/Reference.access$100(Reference.java:11)

            at java/lang/ref/Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:82)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "(Sensor Event Thread)" id=9 idx=0x74 tid=12667 prio=5 alive, native_blocked, daemon

        "VM JFR Buffer Thread" id=10 idx=0x78 tid=12668 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon

        "Timer-0" id=14 idx=0x80 tid=12671 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Waiting for notification on: java/util/TaskQueue@0x92b0ad40[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)

            at java/util/TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)

            ^-- Lock released while waiting: java/util/TaskQueue@0x92b0ad40[fat lock]

            at java/util/TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=15 idx=0x84 tid=12672 prio=1 alive, native_blocked, daemon

            at java/util/AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:119)[optimized]

            at java/util/ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:131)[inlined]

            at javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase$FacetsMap.keySetIterator(UIComponentBase.java:2228)[inlined]

            at javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase$FacetsMapValuesIterator.<init>(UIComponentBase.java:2583)[inlined]

            at javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase$FacetsMapValues.iterator(UIComponentBase.java:2567)[optimized]

            at org/ajax4jsf/component/UIDataAdaptorBase.restoreChildState(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:1006)[optimized]

            at org/ajax4jsf/component/UIDataAdaptorBase.restoreChildState(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:1004)[inlined]



            at org/apache/el/MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)

            at com/sun/facelets/el/TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)

            at javax/faces/component/MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)

            at com/sun/faces/application/ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)

            at com/CompName/AppName/core/web/CustomActionListener.processAction(CustomActionListener.java:51)

            at javax/faces/component/UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)

            at org/ajax4jsf/component/AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)

            at org/ajax4jsf/component/AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)

            at org/ajax4jsf/component/AjaxViewRoot$$com_CompName_AppName_validation_web_ProxyViewRootInterceptor.CGLIB$processEvents$12(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Lorg/ajax4jsf/event/EventsQueue;Z)V(<generated>)[inlined]

            at weblogic/security/service/SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)

            at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)[optimized]

            at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "JFR request timer" id=16 idx=0x88 tid=12673 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Waiting for notification on: java/util/TaskQueue@0x92b0adc0[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)

            at java/util/TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:483)

            ^-- Lock released while waiting: java/util/TaskQueue@0x92b0adc0[fat lock]

            at java/util/TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "weblogic.time.TimeEventGenerator" id=18 idx=0x8c tid=12674 prio=9 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/time/common/internal/TimeTable@0x92b0c1d0[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)

            at weblogic/time/common/internal/TimeTable.snooze(TimeTable.java:286)

            ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/time/common/internal/TimeTable@0x92b0c1d0[fat lock]

            at weblogic/time/common/internal/TimeEventGenerator.run(TimeEventGenerator.java:117)

            at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "JMAPI event thread" id=19 idx=0x90 tid=12675 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon

        "weblogic.timers.TimerThread" id=20 idx=0x94 tid=12676 prio=9 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/timers/internal/TimerThread@0x92b0aec8[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)

            at weblogic/timers/internal/TimerThread$Thread.run(TimerThread.java:262)

            ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/timers/internal/TimerThread@0x92b0aec8[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=21 idx=0x98 tid=12677 prio=1 alive, native_blocked, daemon

            at com/sun/faces/config/ConfigureListener.attributeRemoved(ConfigureListener.java:321)[optimized]

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/EventsManager.notifyRequestAttributeEvent(EventsManager.java:352)[inlined]

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/RequestEventsFilter$EventsRequestWrapper.removeAttribute(RequestEventsFilter.java:58)[optimized]

            at com/sun/faces/context/RequestMap.remove(ExternalContextImpl.java:1096)[optimized]

            at org/ajax4jsf/component/UIDataAdaptorBase.removeVariable(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:583)[inlined]

            at org/ajax4jsf/component/UIDataAdaptorBase.setupVariable(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:559)[inlined]

            at org/richfaces/component/UITree.setupVariable(UITree.java:360)[optimized]

            at org/ajax4jsf/component/UIDataAdaptorBase.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:357)[optimized]

            at org/ajax4jsf/component/UIDataAdaptorBase.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:324)[inlined]

            at org/richfaces/component/state/TreeState.expandNode(TreeState.java:233)[inlined]

            at com/CompName/AppName/application/group/tree/AppNameTree.expandNode(AppNameTree.java:311)[optimized]


            at org/ajax4jsf/component/AjaxViewRoot$$com_CompName_AppName_validation_web_ProxyViewRootInterceptor.CGLIB$processPhase$9(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/event/PhaseId;Lorg/ajax4jsf/context/InvokerCallback;)V(<generated>)[inlined]

            at org/ajax4jsf/component/AjaxViewRoot$$com_CompName_AppName_validation_web_ProxyViewRootInterceptor$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b62d5b05.invoke(ILjava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;(<generated>)[optimized]

            at net/sf/cglib/proxy/MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:167)[inlined]

            at com/CompName/AppName/validation/web/ProxyViewRootInterceptor.intercept(ProxyViewRootInterceptor.java:172)[optimized]


            at weblogic/servlet/internal/RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:527)

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)

            at com/CompName/AppName/core/web/CustomFilter.processRequest(CustomFilter.java:281)[inlined]

            at com/CompName/AppName/core/web/conversation/ConversationFilter.doFilter(ConversationFilter.java:97)[optimized]

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)[optimized]

            at com/CompName/AppName/application/AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:84)

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)[optimized]

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)[optimized]

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)

            at weblogic/security/acl/internal/AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)

            at weblogic/security/service/SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)

            at weblogic/servlet/internal/ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)

            at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)[optimized]

            at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=24 idx=0x9c tid=12678 prio=5 alive, blocked, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Blocked trying to get lock: java/lang/String@0x92a32e70[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForUnblockSignal()V(Native Method)

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.fatLockBlockOrSpin(Locks.java:1402)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.lockFat(Locks.java:1503)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStageHard(Locks.java:1045)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStage(Locks.java:996)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnter(Locks.java:2170)[optimized]

            at weblogic/socket/EPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(EPollSocketMuxer.java:153)

            at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)

            at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)

            at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)

            at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=25 idx=0xa0 tid=12679 prio=5 alive, blocked, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Blocked trying to get lock: java/lang/String@0x92a32e70[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForUnblockSignal()V(Native Method)

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.fatLockBlockOrSpin(Locks.java:1402)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.lockFat(Locks.java:1503)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStageHard(Locks.java:1045)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStage(Locks.java:996)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnter(Locks.java:2170)[optimized]

            at weblogic/socket/EPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(EPollSocketMuxer.java:153)

            at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)

            at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)

            at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)

            at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=26 idx=0xa4 tid=12680 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon

            at jrockit/ext/epoll/EPoll.epollWait0(ILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;II)I(Native Method)

            at jrockit/ext/epoll/EPoll.epollWait(EPoll.java:115)

            at weblogic/socket/EPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(EPollSocketMuxer.java:156)

            ^-- Holding lock: java/lang/String@0x92a32e70[fat lock]

            at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)

            at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)

            at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)

            at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=27 idx=0xa8 tid=12681 prio=5 alive, blocked, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Blocked trying to get lock: java/lang/String@0x92a32e70[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForUnblockSignal()V(Native Method)

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.fatLockBlockOrSpin(Locks.java:1402)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.lockFat(Locks.java:1503)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStageHard(Locks.java:1045)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStage(Locks.java:996)[optimized]

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnter(Locks.java:2170)[optimized]

            at weblogic/socket/EPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(EPollSocketMuxer.java:153)

            at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)

            at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)

            at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)

            at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "Timer-1" id=28 idx=0xac tid=12683 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Waiting for notification on: java/util/TaskQueue@0x92b0c9b0[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)

            at java/util/TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:483)

            ^-- Lock released while waiting: java/util/TaskQueue@0x92b0c9b0[fat lock]

            at java/util/TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "VDE Transaction Processor Thread" id=31 idx=0xb0 tid=12684 prio=2 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Waiting for notification on: com/octetstring/vde/backend/standard/TransactionProcessor@0x92b0ba48[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)

            at com/octetstring/vde/backend/standard/TransactionProcessor.waitChange(TransactionProcessor.java:367)

            ^-- Lock released while waiting: com/octetstring/vde/backend/standard/TransactionProcessor@0x92b0ba48[fat lock]

            at com/octetstring/vde/backend/standard/TransactionProcessor.run(TransactionProcessor.java:212)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "DoSManager" id=34 idx=0xb8 tid=12686 prio=6 alive, sleeping, native_waiting, daemon

            at java/lang/Thread.sleep(J)V(Native Method)

            at com/octetstring/vde/DoSManager.run(DoSManager.java:433)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "Timer-2" id=35 idx=0xbc tid=12687 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Waiting for notification on: java/util/TaskQueue@0x92b0ce80[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)

            at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)

            at java/util/TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)

            ^-- Lock released while waiting: java/util/TaskQueue@0x92b0ce80[fat lock]

            at java/util/TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace


        "[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=37 idx=0xc4 tid=13075 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x872bbdf0[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.wait(Locks.java:1964)[inlined]

            at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)[inlined]

            at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:205)[optimized]

            ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x872bbdf0[fat lock]

            at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:226)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=38 idx=0xc8 tid=13076 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon

            -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x872e99f8[fat lock]

            at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)

            at jrockit/vm/Locks.wait(Locks.java:1964)[inlined]

            at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)[inlined]

            at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:205)[optimized]

            ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x872e99f8[fat lock]

            at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:226)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "ConversationReaper" id=44 idx=0xe0 tid=13104 prio=5 alive, sleeping, native_waiting, daemon

            at java/lang/Thread.sleep(J)V(Native Method)

            at com/CompName/AppName/core/web/conversation/ConversationManager$ConversationReaper.run(ConversationManager.java:405)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace


        "DynamicListenThread[Default]" id=47 idx=0xe8 tid=13106 prio=9 alive, in native, daemon

            at java/net/PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Ljava/net/SocketImpl;)V(Native Method)

            at java/net/PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)

            ^-- Holding lock: java/net/SocksSocketImpl@0x9224b198[biased lock]

            at java/net/ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)

            at java/net/ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)

            at weblogic/socket/WeblogicServerSocket.accept(WeblogicServerSocket.java:38)

            at weblogic/server/channels/DynamicListenThread$SocketAccepter.accept(DynamicListenThread.java:535)

            at weblogic/server/channels/DynamicListenThread$SocketAccepter.access$200(DynamicListenThread.java:417)

            at weblogic/server/channels/DynamicListenThread.run(DynamicListenThread.java:173)

            at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace

        "DynamicListenThread[Default[1]]" id=48 idx=0xec tid=13107 prio=9 alive, in native, daemon

            at java/net/PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Ljava/net/SocketImpl;)V(Native Method)

            at java/net/PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)

            ^-- Holding lock: java/net/SocksSocketImpl@0x922a64b0[biased lock]

            at java/net/ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)

            at java/net/ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)

            at weblogic/socket/WeblogicServerSocket.accept(WeblogicServerSocket.java:38)

            at weblogic/server/channels/DynamicListenThread$SocketAccepter.accept(DynamicListenThread.java:535)

            at weblogic/server/channels/DynamicListenThread$SocketAccepter.access$200(DynamicListenThread.java:417)

            at weblogic/server/channels/DynamicListenThread.run(DynamicListenThread.java:173)

            at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

            at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)

            -- end of trace



        Blocked lock chains

        ===================

        Chain 2:

        "ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=25 idx=0xa0 tid=12679 waiting for java/lang/String@0x92a32e70 held by:

        "ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=26 idx=0xa4 tid=12680 in chain 1

        Chain 3:

        "ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=27 idx=0xa8 tid=12681 waiting for java/lang/String@0x92a32e70 held by:

        "ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=26 idx=0xa4 tid=12680 in chain 1

        Open lock chains

        ================

        Chain 1:

        "ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=24 idx=0x9c tid=12678 waiting for java/lang/String@0x92a32e70 held by:

        "ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=26 idx=0xa4 tid=12680 (active)
```

Comment: A stuck thread does not always mean that the thread is waiting for something. It can simply takes a long time to execute the request. One thread dump is not enough to analyze the problem. Take several thread dumps to check what threads are doing.

Comment: only you can tell that with a profiler.  you should also see which thread is consuming the most cpu: http://code.nomad-labs.com/2010/11/18/identifying-which-java-thread-is-consuming-most-cpu/

Comment: Thanks, next time this happens I'll take a few dumps and see if get more information as to what they are doing. I didn't see any activity at the Oracle database level (no locks or active sessions). These threads were running for 24 hours before I finally restarted the system, I'm pretty confident that they were never going to complete.

Execute Thread 1 and 3 were consuming %100 CPU each, for a total of %200.

Thanks duffymo for that website, I think that will prove useful.